# Do you need causal models when doing counterfactual predictions?

Tags: econometrics, prediction, causality

I am modeling the impact the number of a certain type of company (bottom of pyramid (BOP) companies, ie. companies that cater to the poorest consumers) have on market price.  I considered the following two models:

(1) The first model was designed to capture causal effects; we instrumented the number of BOP companies to estimate the causal relationship between the number of BOP companies on average market price.  I happy with this model.

(2) I am a bit puzzled about the second model I am considering.  What I am trying to do now is to estimate the total income had no BOP company entered the market, and the total market income had these companies entered the market earlier.  There are around 100 different markets being considering, covering around 10 years. Suppose we were to estimate the total income of these markets if no BOP company entered in any of them.  Using the model from part (1), and inputing the number of BOP companies as zero, I can predict what would have happend if there were no BOP companies over the observed years.  From this point, I can basically compute the total market revenue.  My question is:

QUESTION:
Is it right to use the model of step (1) on step (2)?  Do I really have to care about endogeneity when what I want is to do a prediction of the type in (2)?  More troublesome, it is actually wrong to restrict myself to a model of type (1) when I want to do step (2)?

Comment: "Counterfactual" is often used to denote a specific philosophical perspective on causality and relatedly in causal estimation, so your use of the word in your question is a bit puzzling. See for example, Maldonado, G. and Greenland, S. (2002). Estimating causal effects. *International Journal of Epidemiology*, 31(2):422–438.